# Which is the best Ubuntu version to use for ROS?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to be able to use it for ARDrone project and maybe more advanced stuff later on. Which Ubuntu version would be the best to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233818/which-is-the-best-ubuntu-version-to-use-for-ros?/) by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-05-07**:
since currently ros kinetic kame is still in development and indio will be supported for the next two years I would definitely go for 14.04.X because this version has the most prebuild packages you can download via apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you want to minimize the amount of building released packages from source, but also want to have well tested software and new features and modern hardware support, so 16.04 + kinetic may be too new for you, and 12.04 + hydro is falling off the end of life so is too old.

If you plan to buy a new motherboard next year with next year's cpu architecture it may only be properly supported by 16.04, which forces you to use kinetic, but jade or indigo is more stable if you can go to an older ubuntu.

Upgrading isn't a huge issue though either hydro onward, just going one version forward (or backward if necessary) shouldn't be too hard.

From each wiki.ros.org/xxxx/Installation/Ubuntu page where xxxx is the ros version name:

```
kinetic:     15.10, 16.04
jade:        14.04, 14.10, 15.04
indigo:      13.10, 14.04
hydro:       12.04, 12.10, 13.04
groovy:      11.10, 12.04, 12.10
fuerte:      10.04, 11.10, 12.04
electric:    10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10
diamondback: 10.04, 10.10, 11.04  
cturtle:     9.04, 9.10, 10.04, 10.10
```

See also http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/ReleasePolicy

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-05-07**:
The official target platforms are listed in REP 3: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html